# .NET Web Api Token Authentication Rest Service "Get" Method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to access the following URL: 
http://appointmentreminder4.azurewebsites.net/Profile

This URL uses a "Get" method, and is supposed to provide JSON results. Before accessing the URL, you need to login using your Email Address and Password. After logging in successfully, the Web API issues a token. This token is used in ALL communications going forward.

I am currently unable to retrieve the token in Objective-C. I have attempted to google this problem, but I cannot figure out:

1) How to get the token

2) How to get the JSON output from the URL.

Here is the code I have written so far that returns neither the JSON, nor the token:

```
    NSDictionary *postDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Email Adress", @"MyEmailAddress",
                              @"Password", @"MyPassword",
                              nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *localData = nil;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://appointmentreminder4.azurewebsites.net/home"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    if (error == nil)
    {
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        // Send the request and get the response
        localData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:localData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Post result : %@", result);
    }
```

If the above link fails, use this link to navigate to the specific page:

http://appointmentreminder4.azurewebsites.net/home

Comment: Note: Do not test `error` to see if there is an error, that is not reliable, instead test the result of the operation for nil. Further, test for an error immediately after the operation that might return in error,not after other operations. Always test for errors, you are not testing of an error after `sendSynchronousRequest`, do so and at least `NSLog()` the error if there is one.

Comment: Add the logging as above and add any error results to the question.